# Grant all the privileges to user in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on SQL Server. I created a new login, new user to the database then I log into the instance with `sql server authentification` using the same login.
I gave the user all the privileges by [checking these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmoh2.png)

I've run the command :

```
grant all to [user]
```

and got this error

> Cannot grant, deny or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner, information_schema, sys or yourself.

and then still can't save changes and update tables because it's not permitted.
how can I grant all the privileges  the the user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "all privileges"? Though the error is telling you the problem; you can't log in as the *new* user (called `user`) and then use `grant all to [user]` for the reason the error tells you.

Comment: I cannot update tables @Larnu

Comment: That doesn't explain what "all priviledges" mean. If you want a `USER` to be able to do anything in a `DATABASE` give them the `db_owner` role. If you want a `LOGIN` to do anything on a server, give them the `sysadmin` server role. If you want something else, you need to explain what that *something else* is.

Comment: i'm sorry this is the first time I work with sql server so I don't have much knowledge about it I appreciate your help, and yes I want this user to be able to create databases, change tables and columns @Larnu

Comment: If you want _everything possible_ with regards to permissions, log in as sa and add the login in question to the sysadmin server role.  Do not make a regular practice of this, though.

Comment: As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql), `GRANT ALL` does not even grant every possible privilege -- for compatibility purposes. It should basically never be used. Owners and sysadmins truly have every privilege, and for anything less a specific list of permissions should always be used rather than `ALL` -- if for nothing else but clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Grant permissions using SA user because you can not give restricted permissions to yourself if you don't have permission to do it.